# How to integrate oAuth2.0 with Spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

we are not able to use this implementation '''org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server''' with spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE as it is showing
**Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:.
Required by:
project :**
Any Idea and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This artifact is only available starting from version 2.1.0. You can see available versions in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server).

I'm not sure if you can make version 2.1.0 work with Spring Boot 1.5.8, I doubt so. I think you'll have to increase your spring boot version.

Comment: I increase the spring boot version to 2.1.0 but getting this error **error: cannot find symbol
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.DataSourcePublicMetrics;
                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataSourcePublicMetrics
  location: package org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint**

Comment: Sounds like you're missing spring boot actuator dependency. Or you have it in an older version.

Comment: I dont want to increase the spring version as it will break my whole repo so is there any other way apat from increasing the spring version

Comment: You can try using only spring boot starter oauth on its lowest version with the rest of the components on 1.5.8, maybe it will work but I don't think so... if they don't offer support for versions lower than 2.1.0 then you can always implement what you need on your own

Comment: `I dont want to increase the spring version` sometimes you need to do things you dont want to. 1.5.8 is from 2017, you should regularly update your applications, most likely you are having many security issues in your application due to not updating.